# How to import my robot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've to import a robot that I've made with pro-e. I've assembled it in xml and then I want to spaw it on gazebo. I don't know how to do it.
I've tried to convert the xml file in urdf, so I tried to use rosrun gazebo spawn_model, but nothing happens.
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42625/how-to-import-my-robot?/) by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on 2012-08-30**:
What do you mean by "nothing happened"? Usually you should see some error messages if you can't spawn a robot. What parameters have you used for spawn_model?

**Comment by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on 2012-09-01**:
thanka lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i just import my robot into gazebo successfully. here are my steps:

1. create the URDF file for my robot;
2. open a terminal, type in: roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch    this loads an empty world into gazebo;
3. open another terminal, type in: rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file some_directory/my_robot.urdf -urdf -z 0 -model myRobot

one thing to attention about urdf: you need to define the inertial for every robot link. check here for how to define the inertial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model

hope that helps~

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1